# How to get connect to core database in sitecore

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitecore

How to get connect to core database in sitecore 
How to get values of item from core database in sitecore.

```
Sitecore.Data.Database coredb = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("core");
```

I'm working with the above mentioned code but I'm unable to get the values

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Items in the Sitecore core database are not readable for all users, the Anonymous user has default no Read rights in the core database.
Check with the Access Viewer the Read right of the Item you want.

I think you need to use the SecurityDisabler in you code or the UserSwitcher or give read access.

This will work:

```
using Sitecore.SecurityModel;

.....


Sitecore.Data.Database coredb = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("core");

using (new SecurityDisabler())
{
  var a = coredb.GetItem("/sitecore");
}
```

Comment: I would not suggest using SecurityDisabler() for a live site unless you know the implications of what you are doing. The safest approach is to use UserSwitcher to run the command(s) on an account wth **the least privileges required** to perform the action.